# Python Sum if: using data from a different pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sum

I am trying to sum the total number of occurences of a variable in each year for a set of years.

I have a dataframe with one column stating the year and one column where the variable is equal to one or zero. I am wanting to do this for a number of variables so varlist is a list of the names of these columns.

I have tried something similar to:

```
appended_topics= [] 
for s in varlist:
    for x in range (1970, 2018):
        appended_topics.append([x,s,sum(data[s] if data['year']==x)])

topics_df = pd.DataFrame(appended_topics, columns=['year' , 'var', 'count'])
```

However the sum command is not correct. How do I correctly use the if command here in conjunction with sum?

Comment: You might want to look at `groupby`: `data.groupby('year').sum()`

Comment: Was fixed very simply using this! Thanks!